# How to loop over a List of Tables in SQLAlchemy ORM?

Tags: python, postgresql, serialization, sqlalchemy, orm

I'm currently trying to create a number of tables with a 1-many relationship and serialize them so that I can expose them to my frontend.
I've found a previous solution for serialization before, which was creating a serialize() method in each of the classes. However, as I have some 1-many relationships, I'm not sure how to access the serialize method of each one of those when using a List.
Here is an example of a class

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, mapped_column, Mapped, relationship
from typing import List

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_account"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    first_name: Mapped[str]
    last_name: Mapped[str]
    email_address: Mapped[str]
    phone_number: Mapped[str]

    company: Mapped["Company"] = relationship(back_populates="user")
    courses: Mapped[List["Course"]] = relationship(back_populates="user")

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "firstName": self.first_name,
            "lastName": self.last_name,
            "emailAddress": self.email_address,
            "phoneNumber": self.phone_number,
            "company": self.company.serialize(), ## This works because it is a 1-1 relationship and I can directly access the serialize method on the company instance
            # "courses": self.courses ## Here I can't access the property because it is of type List and not of type Course
        }
```

I've already tried to simply loop over it, as you would be able to do in a normal List

```
    serialized_courses = []
    for course in courses:
        serialized_courses.append(course.serialize())
```

However this does not work. Can someone help?